# how to compare input array with mysql column?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Following is  my code showing some error  in mysql query:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$str=$_GET["message"];
$stor=explode(" ",$str);// converting message into array
mysql_select_db('words',$con);
for($j=0;$j<=30; $j++)
{
mysql_query($con,"UPDATE blacklist SET $stor=1 where $stor=0");//if column name=element in array then make it as 1 in database
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: The usual usage for mysql_query is `mysql_query("Query", $Con);`

Comment: don't use mysql_* (are [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) , use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead

Comment: `$stor` is an array..you can't use arrays in a query

Comment: In regards to providing the error message: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGt5f70K02Q

Answer (score 1):

1. Your code is vulnerable to **SQL Injection**. Read up on prepared statements and use **PDO/MySQLi**.
2. $stor is an array object and cant be used directly in the query. If you want to use it, try using

> IN('.implode(",", $stor).')

the code above does the following:

**implode()** - takes an array and turns it into a comma separated string.

**IN()** - compares the given comma separated values and returns true if at least one of them exists.

**Example (implode):**

> implode(",", array(1,2,3)) IS EQUAL TO "1,2,3"

**Example (IN):**

> TestID IN (1,2,3) IS SAME AS (TestID = 1 OR TestID = 2 OR TestID = 3)

Comment: Perhaps explain what your snippet is doing, judging by the user who posted this question, he might not know the full extent of what it's doing

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting a mysql error because your query ends up looking like this

```
UPDATE blacklist SET Array=1 where Array=0;
```

If you're just echoing out a full array, you get `Array` instead, you'll need to specify an array element (`$stor[1]` for example).

What you'll want to do is replace your for loop with a foreach so that you can just throw out the elements one at a time.

Also, your arguments are backwards.

```
foreach($stor as $word)
{
  mysql_query("UPDATE blacklist SET $word=1 where $word=0", $con);
}
```

Comment: You fixed the mysql_query argument before I could make a comment ;)

Comment: ^^^it showing following Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\wamp\www\finalsem\log.php on line 12

Comment: Turn the arguments around, put the query first, and `$con` second. `$con` is the resource and needs to be second.